# Convert file from .img to .bin

Tags: linux, windows, file-extension, img

I need to convert an img file to a bin one.I have tried with power iso but nothing.I also used any burn but it gives me an error.How can I convert the file?

Answer (score 1):

Convert Image File to BIN / CUE

```
1.Run PowerISO.
2.Choose "Tools > Convert" Menu.
3.PowerISO shows Image File to BIN Converter dialog.
4.Choose the source image file you want to convert.
5.Set the output file format to bin / cue.
6.Choose the output bin file name.
7.Click "OK" button to start converting.
```

if this is not working for you, then find program called 'Isobuster'